# How to add new class and attributes to div if it exists on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, visual-studio-2015

I need JavaScript code on my master page which tries to find if a div exists.  If so, it should add a new class and also add a new id attribute.

For example if the page has this div:

```
<div id="Top" class="toplink">abc..</div>
```

Then JavaScript code should make it exactly like this:

```
<div id="Top" class="toplink adin" id-adi="114">abc..</div>
```

The code inside the div should remain the same.

Comment: Is `id-adi` a valid attribute?

Comment: What have you tried? Provide your script. It should be a simple matter of selecting the div, adding the class, and adding your custom attribute (which I would suggest doing as a data- attribute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all of you
following code is working for me

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if ($('.toplink').length > 0) {
        $('.toplink').addClass('adin').attr('data-aid', '114');
    }
});
</script>
```

answered by iamruss

As i am new to stackoverflow, i ask almost same question  at [Add new class and attributes to div if it exists on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619742/add-new-class-and-attributes-to-div-if-it-exists-on-the-page)

Answer (score 1):

can't you just do:

```
$('#Top').addClass("toplink adin")
```

because if it doesn't exist, than it won't add a class.

Answer (score 0):

The atrribute you are trying to set is not valid, use something like `data-*` as someone said.

```
    jQuery.fn.exists = function(){return this.length>0;}

    if ($('#Top').exists()) {
        $('#Top').addClass('adin').attr('data-adi', '114');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `id-adi` attribute is not a valid HTML attribute, but if you wish to set it anyway do:

```
if ($("#Top").length) {
    $("#Top").addClass('adin').attr('id-adi', 114);
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kCjqY/)