# Add new class and attributes to div if it exists on the page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add new class and attributes to div if it exists on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618822/how-to-add-new-class-and-attributes-to-div-if-it-exists-on-the-page)

I need JavaScript code on my master page which tries to find if a div exists. If so, it should add a new class and also add a new id attribute.
For example if the page has this div:

```
<div class="toplink">abc..</div>
```

Then JavaScript code should make it exactly like this:

```
<div class="toplink adin" data-aid="114">abc..</div>
```

The code inside the div should remain the same.

I tried this code but this is not working

```
    <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript">
    if ($('.toplink').exists()) {
        $('.toplink').addClass('adin').attr('data-aid', '114');
    }
</script>
```

What wrong with this code? what where i placed this code,in header on footer?
Can i do this with javascript, not jquery

Comment: And what does this have to do with C# ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $().length property instead, and place this snippet at the very bottom of the page, before closing body tag

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if ($('.toplink').length > 0) {
        $('.toplink').addClass('adin').attr('data-aid', '114');
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: O AAwesome :)
Thanks you so much, its working now with this code

Comment: it was in OP code. I am giving answer that will work for him.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
.attr('data-aid','114')
```

use the `.data` method:

```
.data('aid','114')
```

http://api.jquery.com/data

Comment: Is the final result the same or not? Is it faster or what's the difference? :-)

Comment: That rather depends on what you want the `data-` attribute for.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is probably just running before the DOM is ready. wrap as follows:

```
$(function() {
    $('.toplink').addClass('adin').attr('data-aid', '114');
});
```

Comment: Plus you don't need to check if the element exists - if it doesn't the selector wont return any items.